# Why do I get JSON String decode error when using extjs ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

Below is my code..

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url:'test.jsp',
            params:{id:id,password:password},
            success:function(response){
                 console.log(response);
                 var results = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);                     
                if(results.success){
                    document.location.href="../home.jsp";
                }
            }
        })
```

I got an error saying:

```
Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:
```

and console.log show

```
Object {request: Object, requestId: 1, status: 200, statusText: "OK", responseText: "↵↵↵↵↵"…}
```

If I change code to 
(I am using url to pass my parameters):

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url:'test.jsp?id=' + id + '&password=' + password,
            success:function(response){
                 console.log(response);
                 var results = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);                     
                if(results.success){
                    document.location.href="../home.jsp";
                }
            }
        })
```

console.log will show

```
Object {request: Object, requestId: 1, status: 200, statusText: "OK", responseText: "{success:true,msg:'success',url:'../main.jsp'}↵↵↵↵↵"…}
```

and everything works.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Could you add an example of the JSON string you are trying to parse in the first example?

Comment: Thanks for reply and I edit the question to include the response data.

Comment: It looks like responseData is abbreviated (it has '...' after it). Are you sure that is all the response data you get?

Answer (score 0):

you might pass `true` to the second params, to make it savemode.

```
// your code should like:
Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText, true);
```

it wouldnt solve your problem, but remove the errors.

you still need to check your json, make sure its valid.

Answer (score 0):

An empty string isn't valid JSON. You can run `JSON.parse('')` and it will throw an exception.

If you run `JSON.parse('{}')` then it's ok.